# Swift : Save & Show selected indexPath in static Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a little problem with my static tableview. I have a PopOver which is shown as an option for my grid. I want to save the state(indexPath) of my static TableView but seems it doesnt work, below is my snippet code :

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var currSelected: IndexPath?

    let section = indexPath.section
    let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section) as IndexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = row == indexPath.row ? .checkmark : .none
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            currSelected = indexPath

            if section == 2 {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
            else {
                delegate?.option(lastSelected: currSelected!)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reload"), object: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use `delegate` to throw the `lastSelected` (last indexPath) to previous controller and send it back to the Pop Over Controller and i got it. But i dont know to show the checkmark using this lastSelected. And the `prepare for cell at` function need a identifier for a reused cell but i dont use it.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407723/checkmark-on-static-cells-uitableview) for showing the checkmark but its not saving the state. I have read [this](https://blog.apoorvmote.com/how-to-use-static-cells-to-save-app-settings/) too but its same too. Any suggestions/answer will help for me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath == lastSelected {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}
```

Comment: its only save one checkmark. I have 2 section that cant be chekced, so i need 2 checkmark if lastSelected have two checkmark

Comment: Then you need to store an array of IndexPaths instead of an IndexPath variable and in `willDisplayCell`, loop through that array

Comment: Its work with separated indexPath. Accept as usefull sugest, i will update my final code. Thanks in advance